# optimize SELECT query, knowing that we are dealing with a limited range

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am trying to include in a MYSQL SELECT query a limitation.
My database is structured in a way, that if a record is found in column one then only 5000 max records with the same name can be found after that one.

Example:

```
mark
..mark repeated 5000 times
john
anna
..other millions of names
```

So in this table it would be more efficent to find the first Mark, and continue to search maximum 5000 rows down from that one.

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: You're looking to skip searching the next 5000 rows for every new name found or just certain names like Mark?

Comment: I am looking to do this: If a record is found, then continue the search only for the next 5000 rows. Then stop. Because the records are grouped together and their max repetition number is 5000!

Comment: It's not clear (at all) what you want to achieve. Can you show us your SELECT query?

Comment: In SQL, there is nothing like "next 5000 rows". Next in what order?

Comment: Either you would need to `ORDER BY` which will scan all rows/index. Or you just select out the rows `WHERE name = "Mark"` first and filter again. Which will also scan all rows/index.

Comment: To do something like what ? What is your query supposed to return ? can you give an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Guys, sorry if I my explainations are not clear.
My idea is very simple: I know that NO MORE THAN 5000 results exist for a given value.
IMPORTANT: note that equal values are stored one row after the other sequentially.
So when doing a select statement, I would like mysql to STOP searching at the row in which the value was found + 5000 rows.
Because I know that after 5000 rows, continuing a table scan would be useless!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a btree index on the name column:

```
CREATE INDEX name ON your_table(name) USING BTREE
```

and mysql will silently do exactly what you want each time it looks for a name.

Comment: ok I tried your suggestion and I read about how BTREE indexes work. My query now takes 0.008 seconds instead of 0.2 so that's a big improvement! Another question: will a primary key further increase the performance? (Currently there are two columns with Unique Ids and no PK)

Comment: For simple `... WHERE name = 'SomeName'` queries I don't think a primary key have any positive impact on performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
SELECT name
FROM table
ORDER BY (name = 'mark') DESC
LIMIT 5000
```

Basicly you sort mark 1st then the rest follow up and gets limited.

Comment: how does it get limited? I think here the results will be found first, but then the query will continue scanning the rest of the table!

Answer (score 0):

Its actually quite difficult to understand your desired output .... but i think this might be heading in the right direction ?

```
(SELECT name
FROM table
WHERE name = 'mark'
LIMIT 5000)

UNION

(SELECT name
FROM table
WHERE name != 'mark'
ORDER BY name)
```

This will first get upto 5000 records with the first name as `mark` then get the remainder - you can add a `limit` to the second query if required ... using [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

For performance you should ensure that the columns used by `ORDER BY` and `WHERE` are indexed accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If you make sure that the column is properly indexed, MySQL will take care off optimisation for you. 
Edit: 
Thinking about it, I figured that this answer is only useful if I specify how to do that. user nobody beat me to the punch: `CREATE INDEX name ON your_table(name) USING BTREE`

This is exactly what database indexes are designed to do; this is what they are for. MySQL will use the index itself to optimise the search.